# Получить индекс элемента в foreach цикле

Tags: java, циклы, foreach

Есть ли возможность в java получить индекс элемента коллекции в цикле `foreach`?

```
for (String str: array) {

}
```

То есть узнать индекс текущего элемента в теле цикла

Comment: Нет, для работы с индексами стоит использовать обычный `for`

Comment: Не во всех случаях. См. ответ  @Regent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работы с индексами стоит использовать обычный цикл `for`

---

Если "очень хочется", то при условии уникальности элементов массива можно воспользоваться поиском элемента в массиве. Однако этот подход получается всецело хуже обычного for-а:

- работает за O(n^2), что при большом количестве элементов может создать проблемы с производительностью
- требует уникальности элементов массива
- код получается больше и сложнее

Так что этот подход можно рассматривать только для полноты картины:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
for (String str : array)
{
    int index = list.indexOf(str);
    ...
}
```

Вместо метода [List.indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) можно воспользоваться методом [ArrayUtils.indexOf](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) из библиотеки Apache Commons Lang, но суть от этого не меняется - только кода становится чуть меньше

---

Можно ещё использовать дополнительную переменную:

```
int index = 0;
for (String str : array)
{
    ...
    index++;
}
```

но это уже получается почти что обычный for

Answer (score 3):

В Kotlin у коллекций и массивов есть метод [`forEachIndexed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each-indexed.html):

```
list.forEachIndexed { element, index -> 

}
```